# Flutter Navigator - push to Another page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem when i use `Navigator.of(context).push`, at ElevatedButton it doesn't work.
I have two pages Home_Screen And The another one is Body from another file

```
body: Container(

     padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10,horizontal: 5),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(  
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
              Text('PROMOTION',style: TextStyle(color:Colors.orange, fontSize: 20 ),),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).push( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Body(), 
                ),);
                },
                child: Text('Starter',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),),
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your following code:

```
Navigator.of(context).push( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Body()),);
```

to

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Body()),
  );
```

You need to pass a context and route to push method.

For more information about navigator, please go through the following link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 0):

@vaidarbhi: the form is correct in both cases...

@yassir outisket: Body should be a PAGE with scaffold or wont work.

Try next code for make a test with your function:

```
Navigator.of(context).push( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestPage(), ),);
```

And test page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Text("This is a test")
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain mor? it doesn't work

Comment: create a button in main page where in the action (onClick or onPress) put the Navigator... in another file of the project create the stateful class TestPage. it will work as charm.